# Shell.Application Verbs .Net 3.5

Tags: c#

I am attempting to write the following code in .net 3.5. The code is trying to loop through verbs (i.e. Pin to Start, Open, Create Shortcut, etc)

This code does this in 4.5

```
    string path = Path.GetDirectoryName(filePath);
    string fileName = Path.GetFileName(filePath);

    // create the shell application object
    dynamic shellApplication = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Shell.Application"));
    dynamic directory = shellApplication.NameSpace(path);
    dynamic link = directory.ParseName(fileName);
    dynamic verbs = link.Verbs();



    for (int i = 0; i < verbs.Count(); i++)
    {
        dynamic verb = verbs.Item(i);
        var name = verb.Name;
        if (verb.Name.Equals(localizedVerb))
        {
            verb.DoIt();
            return true;
        }
    }
```

I attempted to translate this code in 3.5 as

```
        Shell shellApplication = new ShellClass();
        string path = Path.GetDirectoryName(filePath);
        string fileName = Path.GetFileName(filePath);
        Folder directory = GetShell32NameSpaceFolder(path);
        FolderItem link = directory.ParseName(fileName);
        FolderItemVerbs verbs = link.Verbs();

        for (var i = 0; i < verbs.Count; i++)
        {
            FolderItemVerb verb = verbs.Item(i);

            logger.WriteDebug("Verb Search: " + verb.Name);
            if (verb.Name.Equals(localizedVerb))
            {
                logger.WriteDebug("Verb Found: " + verb.Name);
                verb.DoIt();
                return true;
            }
        }
```

This works well kinda..It finds verbs, but for some reason not the verb im after "Pin to Start".

How can I translate the 4.5 code above into 3.5 so it finds all the verbs for a win10 (or at least a win7) os?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually you already have the answer!
The issue is that verbs in windows are configured against file types. You haven't specified which file type you were looking for, so I have run your code on my machine against some common types, starting with a shortcut, which is the obvious one to pin

> (.lnk) C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Outlook 2016.lnk

```
Verb Search: &Open
Verb Search: Open file locat&ion
Verb Search: Run as &administrator
Verb Search: Troubleshoot compatibilit&y
Verb Search: &Pin to Start
Verb Search: Scan with Windows Defender...
Verb Search: Restore previous &versions
Verb Search: 
Verb Search: Cu&t
Verb Search: &Copy
Verb Search: Create &shortcut
Verb Search: &Delete
Verb Search: Rena&me
Verb Search: P&roperties
```

Now if I run the same for a text file:

> (.txt) \\PDC\Folder Redirection\chris\Documents\who knows.txt

```
Verb Search: &Open
Verb Search: &Print
Verb Search: &Edit
Verb Search: Scan with Windows Defender...
Verb Search: 
Verb Search: Restore previous &versions
Verb Search: 
Verb Search: Cu&t
Verb Search: &Copy
Verb Search: Create &shortcut
Verb Search: &Delete
Verb Search: Rena&me
Verb Search: P&roperties
```

Now if I run the same for a folder:

> (Directory) \\PDC\Folder Redirection\chris\Documents

```
Verb Search: &Open
Verb Search: Pin to Quick access
Verb Search: Open in &Visual Studio
Verb Search: Scan with Windows Defender...
Verb Search: Restore previous &versions
Verb Search: &Pin to Start
Verb Search: 
Verb Search: Cu&t
Verb Search: &Copy
Verb Search: Create &shortcut
Verb Search: &Delete
Verb Search: Rena&me
Verb Search: P&roperties
```

So where are these elusive verbs configured? In the registry. See:

[MSDN: Verbs and File Associations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144175(v=vs.85).aspx)

[Registering Verbs for File Name Extensions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb165967.aspx)

> NOTE: If you want to pin a file that does not support pinning IT IS NOT AS SIMPLE AS CREATING A SHORTCUT to that file... I tried that just now, windows still shows the verbs for the target of the shortcut! But that makes sense, because with windows jump lists, we normally pin the program used to open an item and then we can pin the item inside that program's jumplist.

Just for fun, I've added my code exploration for attempting to create the shortcut, just in case someone else finds a use for it. I have also altered the log statements to make this run from a console app with limited references.

```
using Shell32; // Add COM reference to Microsoft Shell controls and Automation

static class Program
{
    public const string PIN_TO_START = "&Pin to Start";
    public const string CREATE_SHORTCUT = "Create &shortcut";
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        // Test with a text file, text files do not have "Pin to Start" as a standard verb
        string path = @"\\PDC\Folder Redirection\chris\Documents\who knows.txt";
        string localizedVerb = "&Pin to Start";

        if (ExecuteShellVerb(path, localizedVerb))
            Debug.WriteLine($"Verb '{localizedVerb}' executed on {path}");
        else if (localizedVerb.Equals(PIN_TO_START))
        {
            // Create a shortcut to the item, by cheating with the Create Shortcut verb :)
            // You could do this a number of ways, this is just one idea to point you in the right direction
            if (ExecuteShellVerb(path, CREATE_SHORTCUT))
            {
                // by default the shortcut name will be the same as the item, but with a ' - Shortcut.lnk' appended
                // You know how windows naming conventions work and what the possibilities are here :)
                string shortcutPath = $"{path} - Shortcut.lnk";
                Debug.WriteLine($"Created Shortcut: {shortcutPath}");
                if (ExecuteShellVerb(shortcutPath, localizedVerb))
                    Debug.WriteLine($"Verb '{localizedVerb}' executed on {shortcutPath}");
                else
                    Debug.WriteLine($"Failed to execute verb '{localizedVerb}' on the created shortcut: {shortcutPath}");
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.WriteLine($"Failed to create Shortcut using verb.");
                // TODO: create the shortcut manually
            }
        }
    }

    private static bool ExecuteShellVerb(string filePath, string localizedVerb)
    {
        Shell shellApplication = new ShellClass();

        string path = Path.GetDirectoryName(filePath);
        string fileName = Path.GetFileName(filePath);
        Folder directory = GetShell32NameSpaceFolder(path);
        FolderItem link = directory.ParseName(fileName);
        FolderItemVerbs verbs = link.Verbs();

        for (var i = 0; i < verbs.Count; i++)
        {
            FolderItemVerb verb = verbs.Item(i);

            Debug.WriteLine("Verb Search: " + verb.Name);
            if (verb.Name.Equals(localizedVerb))
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Verb Found: " + verb.Name);
                verb.DoIt();
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public static Shell32.Folder GetShell32NameSpaceFolder(Object folder)
    {
        Type shellAppType = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Shell.Application");

        Object shell = Activator.CreateInstance(shellAppType);
        return (Shell32.Folder)shellAppType.InvokeMember("NameSpace",
        System.Reflection.BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, shell, new object[] { folder });
    }

}
```

And the output from this execution:

```
Verb Search: &Open
Verb Search: &Print
Verb Search: &Edit
Verb Search: Scan with Windows Defender...
Verb Search: 
Verb Search: Restore previous &versions
Verb Search: 
Verb Search: Cu&t
Verb Search: &Copy
Verb Search: Create &shortcut
Verb Search: &Delete
Verb Search: Rena&me
Verb Search: P&roperties
Verb Search: &Open
Verb Search: &Print
Verb Search: &Edit
Verb Search: Scan with Windows Defender...
Verb Search: 
Verb Search: Restore previous &versions
Verb Search: 
Verb Search: Cu&t
Verb Search: &Copy
Verb Search: Create &shortcut
Verb Found: Create &shortcut
Created Shortcut: \\PDC\Folder Redirection\chris\Documents\who knows.txt - Shortcut.lnk
Verb Search: &Open
Verb Search: Open file locat&ion
Verb Search: &Print
Verb Search: &Edit
Verb Search: Scan with Windows Defender...
Verb Search: 
Verb Search: Restore previous &versions
Verb Search: 
Verb Search: Cu&t
Verb Search: &Copy
Verb Search: Create &shortcut
Verb Search: &Delete
Verb Search: Rena&me
Verb Search: P&roperties
Failed to execute verb '&Pin to Start' on the created shortcut: \\PDC\Folder Redirection\chris\Documents\who knows.txt - Shortcut.lnk
```

Comment: I am after a .lnk file type but am not getting the Pin to Start option using the 3.5 code in win10. Do you get Pin to start using the 3.5 code on a win10 machine with a .lnk file?

Comment: Yeah I ran this on my Win 10 .Net 3.5... The version of .Net doesn't affect this so ignore that. (.Net will affect the namespaces and tools that you use, the Verb values come from the windows runtime) So now try it in windows direct, when you right click a .lnk file do you get the option to 'Pin to Start'? That's all your code does right, the context menu calls the same sub-system. So if Pin to Start is not available to general users you will have to inspect the registry settings to ensure the verb is actually registered on your machine for pin to start. See the links in the answer for info.

Comment: I getting this error on Windows 11, when I try to Pin a shortcut or executable on the taskbar:

Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))

Comment: @Auto pin to taskbar has been disabled from scripts globally since build 1909. There are workarounds, this is discussed here: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/windows-10-1909-why-are-pin-to-starttaskbar-verbs/72194716-9d24-4bdd-bb51-3f7f5ae64047