# Do language neutral Filesystem Object Verbs exist for Powershell?

Tags: windows, powershell

When I want to **pin a folder** with Powershell to the **`Quick Access`** section of File Explorer, I do it like this

```
$folderPath = "C:\Windows"
$shell = New-Object -ComObject shell.application 
$folder = $Shell.Namespace("$folderPath").Self
$verb = $folder.Verbs() | Where-Object {$_.Name.replace('&', '') -match 'Pin to Quick access'}
if ($verb) {
    $verb.DoIt()
}
```

Due to the match on the Verb name, this function fails if it runs on a non-english Windows, the **Verb name is language dependant**.

I also found this code that seems to invoke something like a key instead of the Verb name, but it also fails if the OS language is not english.

```
$folder.InvokeVerb("pintohome")
```

Are there any **language neutral Verb "keys"** that work with whatever language version of Windows? If yes, where can I find them?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Shell.Application Verbs .Net 3.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42819959/shell-application-verbs-net-3-5)

Answer (score 3):

Short answer is 'No'.

But it could be worked around if you'll dig into Windows MUI resources and find there the verb for your language.

Unfortunately this workaround has its own drawbacks: these resources are different for each Windows version. You can look here for details about this solution http://alexweinberger.com/main/pinning-network-program-taskbar-programmatically-windows-10/

For the sake of completeness a copy-paste of the code from there (for Windows 7 only):

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true, BestFitMapping = false, ThrowOnUnmappableChar = true)]
internal static extern IntPtr LoadLibrary(string lpLibFileName);

[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true, BestFitMapping = false, ThrowOnUnmappableChar = true)]
internal static extern int LoadString(IntPtr hInstance, uint wID, StringBuilder lpBuffer, int nBufferMax);

public static bool PinUnpinTaskbar(string filePath, bool pin)
{
    if (!File.Exists(filePath)) throw new FileNotFoundException(filePath);
    int MAX_PATH = 255;
    var actionIndex = pin ? 5386 : 5387; // 5386 is the DLL index for"Pin to Tas&kbar", ref. http://www.win7dll.info/shell32_dll.html
    //uncomment the following line to pin to start instead
    //actionIndex = pin ? 51201 : 51394;
    StringBuilder szPinToStartLocalized = new StringBuilder(MAX_PATH);
    IntPtr hShell32 = LoadLibrary("Shell32.dll");
    LoadString(hShell32, (uint)actionIndex, szPinToStartLocalized, MAX_PATH);
    string localizedVerb = szPinToStartLocalized.ToString();

    string path = Path.GetDirectoryName(filePath);
    string fileName = Path.GetFileName(filePath);

    // create the shell application object
    dynamic shellApplication = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Shell.Application"));
    dynamic directory = shellApplication.NameSpace(path);
    dynamic link = directory.ParseName(fileName);

    dynamic verbs = link.Verbs();
    for (int i = 0; i < verbs.Count(); i++)
    {
        dynamic verb = verbs.Item(i);
        if (verb.Name.Equals(localizedVerb))
        {
            verb.DoIt();
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```